# What is the Equivalent of Android's CordovaPlugin remapUri Override for iOS Cordova Plugins

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to alter the URL that the Cordova WebView loads on launch programatically. On Android, I see that I can override `remapUri` using the CordovaPlugin interface. However, I do not see a similar or equivalent method for iOS Plugins. Does anyone know how to accomplish something similar on iOS?

Many Thanks,
Lyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though a little bit late. But yes, there is.

You can intercept urls via overriding

```
- (BOOL)shouldOverrideLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

in your custom plugin. Return `Yes` when you'd like to handle the url yourself.

Check out https://github.com/joyxuLogic/cordova-plugin-iframelinks/blob/master/src/ios/IFrameLinks.m